# VSCODE Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, source-maps

I am trying to use Javascript ES6 with visual studio code, using the [chrome debugger extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome). My code is running in chrome, and even in the debugger extension in vscode, but without sourcemaps. When using sourcemaps, I have an error :

```
Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?).
```

This is likely a path problem, vscode not beeing able to find the original files.

My project structure is:

```
testjs/
├── src/
│   ├── modules.css
|   |   └── person.js
│   └── index.js
├── dist/
│   ├── modules
|   |   ├── person.js
|   |   └── person.js.map
|   ├── index.js 
│   └── index.js.map
```

All the configs file and index.html are in the root (testjs folder). The following command uses files in src and outputs files in dist. index.html includes dist/index.js

```
browserify src/index.js -t [ babelify ] -d | exorcist dist/index.js.map > dist/index.js
```

Sourcemaps paths are as follow:

index.js.map

```
"sources": [
"../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js",
"src\\index.js",
"src\\modules\\person.js"
],
"sourceRoot": ""
```

person.js.map

```
"sources": [
"../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js",
"src\\modules\\person.js"
],
"sourceRoot": "",
```

And my launch.js file:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "url": "file:///C:/<PATH_TO_testjs_FOLDER>/index.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "trace": true
    }
]
```

}

Changing

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
```

to

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
```

seems to work, but for some reason I have to click on Restart 3 times to make it work. So I think there is still something wrong.